# Content becomes disabled when I apply an overlay color on the background image div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with a background image, and at the center of the div, I have text and a button.

The problem is, when I apply an overlay color over the background image the text and button become unclickable, like they're disabled.

I need to be able to click the `Read More` button and make the content visible and selectable.

**jsFiddle** https://jsfiddle.net/yzce0vLt/8/

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-12 dynamic-height">
  <div class="item dynamic-height">
            <div class="item-container dynamic-height content-center overlay-x dark" style="background: url('http://placehold.it/1920x1280') center center; background-size: cover;">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.col-md-12, .item, .item-container {
  height: 600px;
}

/* Align Content */
.content-center {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

/* Background Overlay */
.overlay-x {
    position: relative;
}
.overlay-x:before{
    position: absolute;
    content:" ";
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display: none;
    z-index:0;
}
.overlay-x:before{
    display: block;
}
.dark:before {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.light:before {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Dynamic Height
    $('.dynamic-height').css({'height':($(window).height())+'px'});
    $(window).resize(function(){
        $('.dynamic-height').css({'height':($(window).height())+'px'});
    });
});
```

Comment: That's whats expected when you put the `:before` pseudoelement in front of all other elements, only the foremost element is clickable, not the elements it overlays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your css

```
 .btn {
  z-index: 100;
}
```

This will move the button over your overlay.

Comment: Why can I apply it to `.btn` but not `.item-container` ?

Comment: `.item-container` is the class of the div which also is the overlay. You can apply to it but it will affect everything, included the overlay itself. So you are not moving content on the top of it.